# Java - How to break out of while with hasNext() condition?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am writing a simple program to calculate the average of a set of numbers. You get the numbers using `Scanner`, so I am using `while` loop with `.hasNext()` as a condition. However the loop is infinite.

Is it possible to break out of it without writing some certain word like "stop" in the input?

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int temp;
        int sum = 0;

        while(Input.hasNextInt()){

           count++;           

           temp = Input.nextInt();
           sum += temp;
           System.out.println(temp);
           System.out.println(count);           

        } // End of while

        double average = sum / count;
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);

    } // End of method main

}
```

Comment: You might want to use a sentinel value so that the user specifies when they want to exit.

Comment: How do you want the user to tell the program that there's no more data?

Comment: The problem is that I didn't fully understand how scanner works, when I was writing this.. I ended up using a sentinel value to exit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break;` statement can be sued to... well... break out of an iteration. And by iteration I mean you can get out of a `for` too, for example.

You have to define WHEN do you want to break out of the iteration and then do something like this:

```
while(Input.hasNextInt(Input)){
   if(condition())
       break;

   count++;           

   temp = Input.nextInt();
   sum += temp;
   System.out.println(temp);
   System.out.println(count);           

 }
```

Otherwise, you can make an auxiliary method that defines if the iteration should keep on going, like this one:

```
private boolean keepIterating(Scanner in) {
    boolean someOtherCondition = //define your value here that must evaluate to false
                                 //when you want to stop looping
    return Input.hasNextInt() && someOtherCondition;
}
```

Method that you will have to invoke in your `while`:

```
while(keepIterating()){

   count++;           

   temp = Input.nextInt();
   sum += temp;
   System.out.println(temp);
   System.out.println(count);           

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the keyword `break` to stop the while loop:

```
while(Input.hasNextInt()){

    count++;           

    temp = Input.nextInt();
    sum += temp;
    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(count); 
    break;          

} // End of while
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the magic keyword is `break;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Scanner` will *always* expect an integer from `System.in`. You could break out of the loop using a sentinal value e.g. `-1`:

```
if (temp == -1) {
   break;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter # to end ");
    while( !Input.hasNextInt("#"))// return true if u input value = its argument
    {
        //ur code
    }//end while
```